# Rolify tables are not getting created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rolify

After bundle installing the gem(gem 'rolify'), I have generated the file using the following command,

```
rails g rolify Role User
```

Below files got created,

```
invoke  active_record
create    app/models/role.rb
invoke    rspec
create      spec/models/role_spec.rb
invoke      factory_girl
create        spec/factories/roles.rb
insert    app/models/role.rb
create    db/migrate/20140425070708_rolify_create_roles
insert  app/models/user.rb
create  config/initializers/rolify.rb
```

Then, i gave

```
rake db:migrate
```

Its giving me the warning,

```
[WARN] table 'Role' doesn't exist. Did you run the migration ? Ignoring rolify config.
```

Also tables are not getting created. What is the problem am i missing anything here.?
This my migration file,

```
 class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
     end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, :name)
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
 end
```

My versions,

Rails - 4.1.0
   Ruby - 2.1.1

Please any one help me in this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hm, did you try to reset your database, and running all the migrations from scratch?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a known bug with `rolify`; the migration is created without the `.rb` extension so the `rake db:migrate` doesn't pick it up.

Manually rename your migration to add the .rb extension.  Change:

```
db/migrate/20140425070708_rolify_create_roles
```

to be:

```
db/migrate/20140425070708_rolify_create_roles.rb
```

And then `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Graeme, realy i dint notice that .rb.. :) helpful :)

Comment: With Ruby 2.2 and Rails 4.2 I get the same error message while executing rake db:migrate. The migration file has the .rb extension and the tables are created, however to get rid of the error message just type: rake db:test:prepare and then rake db:test:load

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Rails 5.2.5 and Rolify 5.0.0 and Devise 3.5.3

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'papi_development.roles' doesn't exist: SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
```

I fixed it by commenting out my Devise line in the User model before running the rake db:migrate command.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  # devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  ...
end
```

After the successful migration, i uncommented the devise line and everything seemed to work fine from that point on.